# Can I make my Keras/Tensorflow model use float64 (double) internally?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm running out of precision in my application.  Is it possible to use doubles as input, output and internally?  If so, how do I specify this in the layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets the default float type to

```
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to have some models in float32 and some in float64? When I apply the command you show, it prevents my old models from loading their weights since the type is wrong.  (My workflow is to make the model and load weights as opposed to saving entire models).

Comment: The above way set globally this type. Check here for more details: [set_floatx function](https://keras.io/api/utils/backend_utils/). Also, you can set each layer to the specific type: e.g `tf.keras.layers.Dense(... , dtype=tf.float64)`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in general; for example, with the above call set, `tf.math.log(2*numpy.pi)` still returns a `float32` type: `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.837877>`.  Also there are functions (such as `tf.eye` and `tf.ones`) that have float32 hardcoded as the default dtype that this solution doesn't override

Comment: @charlestoncrabb https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15594#issuecomment-963355295