# How can you save a keras model in 64bit format?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

how can you save a keras model in 64bit format?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187646/can-i-make-my-keras-tensorflow-model-use-float64-double-internally) is able to 'put tensorflow' in 64bit 'mode' for the current runtime. But I've found that even just saving the model & reloading it is sufficient to truncate the 64bit precision & change model outputs.

In particular I would like to save the model is such a way that it would load  automatically in '64 bit mode', and obviously would never lose its precision.

Answer (score -2):

What is the purpose of the requirements when you are using an optimizer larger than e-07?

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import h5py

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
database_buffer = "F:\\models\\buffer\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
database_buffer_dir = os.path.dirname(database_buffer)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
if not exists(database_buffer_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(database_buffer_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + database_buffer_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
# Create hdf5 file
hdf5_file = h5py.File(database_buffer, mode='w')

# Train images
hdf5_file['x_train'] = train_images
hdf5_file['y_train'] = train_labels

# Test images
hdf5_file['x_test'] = test_images
hdf5_file['y_test'] = test_labels

hdf5_file.close()

# Visualize dataset train sample
hdf5_file = h5py.File(database_buffer,  mode='r')

x_train = hdf5_file['x_train'][0: 10000]
x_test = hdf5_file['x_test'][0: 100]
y_train = hdf5_file['y_train'][0: 10000]
y_test = hdf5_file['y_test'][0: 100]

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 3 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(2, 3, activation='relu', padding="same", name="Conv2DTranspose_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4 * 256), 
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((4 * 256, 1)),

    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, return_state=False),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, name='LSTM256'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
])

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense64'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(7))
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1 ,validation_data=(x_train, y_train))
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: it is answered for the purpose of the program and working as your question needs why do you need to save it more accuracy when you can specify the input type for the same purpose?

Comment: That is irrelevant, the answer section is to answer the question, not to ask additional details. For that you can use comments in the question section.